# Can't remove properties java

Tags: java, properties

I'm trying to delete users(key) and passwords(key value) in a properties file, but after removing them, I can still "log in" using the username. My code for deleting the properties is:

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("File.properties");
        properties.load(fileReader);
        properties.remove(username);
        fileReader.close();

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("File.properties", true);
        properties.store(fileWriter, "Updated");
        System.out.println(username + properties.getProperty(username));
        fileWriter.close();
```

This is what the property file looks like after executing the code.

Wed Apr 29 21:31:27 CEST 2015

userr=pass

Updated
Wed Apr 29 21:31:44 CEST 2015

(Removed)

So the key and the key value is gone in the new line, but it's still up there and I can use it. So how can I remove it properly from the property file? 
Sorry if it got messy. Thanks.`

Comment: I think I just solved it by removing "true" from filewriter...I thought it would make a new property file, and delete all the old content, including the values I didnt want to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at official [FileWriter Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html). Second parameter in constructor is flag for deciding whether to append to the file (`true`) or overwrite it (`false`). So as you yourself noticed, by setting it to `true` you only appended properties to existing ones, and whatever was reading them was probably getting the first, original values from the file. Setting it to `false` should solve your problem.

Comment: I thought setting the boolean append to true would erase all the old data in the properties, and that is the part I still don't understand quite yet. The part where I properties.load, is that saved and then applied when I use properties.store? Because it must know somehow know how to write the old data from the properties file to the new file.

Answer (score 1):

as the docs:

> FileWriter(File file, boolean append)
>   Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object.

so if you put true in the second param you append to the file donr override it.